# Replace values in dataframe with wildcard expression

Tags: r, regex, replace

Maybe the solution is simple, but I was not able to find it:

I have a dataframe with two columns - one indicating a depth value, the other one a density value. Density values, that should be treated as NA, have an M attached to them (see below).

```
#input data
Depth Density
0.001 0.3
0.002 0.31M
0.003 0.33
```

I want to replace the values with an M attached; solution should look like this:

```
#desired output
Depth Density
0.001 0.3
0.002 NA
0.003 0.33
```

This does not give me what I wanted

```
df[df == "*M"] <- NA
```

neither does

```
read.table(file, na.strings = "NA, *M")
```

Do I have to use a different wildcard expression? Or is the fact that R treats the density column as factors the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your line should be `read.table(file, na.strings = c("NA", "*M"))` but this wouldn't work either because `na.strings` is matched literally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sub` to find and replace values

```
> df$Density <- as.numeric(sub(".*M", "NA", df$Density))
> df
Depth Density
1 0.001    0.30
2 0.002      NA
3 0.003    0.33
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply coerce to numeric and R will automatically convert non-numeric elements to `NA`.  Since `Density` is (assumed to be) a factor, we will need to coerce it to character first.

```
df$Density <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Density))
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion 
df
#   Depth Density
# 1 0.001    0.30
# 2 0.002      NA
# 3 0.003    0.33
```

If `Density` is a character to begin with, all you need is

```
df$Density <- as.numeric(df$Density)
```